# Is there any limitations on the no.of colors to be used in the page?

Tags: website-design, design, color-scheme, dashboard

Is there any limitation on color usage in the case of a dashboard? Is there any standard pattern followed by any SaaS/B2B companies?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing more than regular color theory of contrast, harmony and overall design principles. But as most of SaaS will have some type of chart or graph following some guidelines regarding data visualization are need. Bellow you can find an article:

https://chartio.com/learn/charts/how-to-choose-colors-data-visualization/